# sql parameter changing error

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

This is my working code

```
strQuery = @"SELECT FROM IBK_CO_USERS where upper(user_id)= upper(:userid) AND co_id= :Com_Id";


  ocommand = new OracleCommand();
  if (db.GetConnection().State == ConnectionState.Open)
  {
   ocommand.CommandText = strQuery;
   ocommand.Connection = db.GetConnection();
   ocommand.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
   ocommand.Parameters["userid"].Value = userID;
   ocommand.Parameters.Add("Com_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
   ocommand.Parameters["Com_Id"].Value = Comid;
   odatareader = ocommand.ExecuteReader();
   odatareader.Read();
  }
```

Again i change like that

```
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("Com_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["Com_Id"].Value = Comid;
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["userid"].Value = userID;`
```

Now it is not working .should i set parameter value according asending order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the following parts where you need to consider:

1. your select statement doesnt include any fields to retrieve, either
   try:

   ```
   SELECT  * FROM IBK_CO_USERS where .....
   ```

   or specify the exact fields you want to fetch
2. You never open the connection: you have to call `db.Open()` (you just check if it is open)
3. Generally the normal way to fetch an sqlreader results is using the
   snippet:

   ```
    odatareader = ocommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (odatareader.Read())
    {
     /// Fetch your data
    }
   ```

In general, As long as you set a parameter name and value and you pair these 2 together  the order of instatination doesn't plays any role, eg:

```
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("Com_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["Com_Id"].Value = Comid;
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["userid"].Value = userID;
```

is equivalent to:

```
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["userid"].Value = userID;
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("Com_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["Com_Id"].Value = Comid;
```

The only way you get a different result is if you change the name-value pairing, eg:

```
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["userid"].Value = Comid;
  ocommand.Parameters.Add("Com_Id", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
  ocommand.Parameters["Com_Id"].Value = userID;
```

results different from the previous 2 examples

However  in `Oracle ODP.Net documentation` it is state that parameters are bound by postition by default. If you want to set it to be bound by name set:

```
ocommand.BindByName = true;
```

Comment: yes code have some issues. but my question is should we set parameter according to query.can we change parameter order??

Comment: i am working in oracle DB and  when i used second way it is not working